# How do I get my rare metal detector back?

Tags: dig-or-die

I may have lost my rare metal detector when I was reconfiguring my toolbar. When I cleared it, I dragged many of the icons into the world, which with a bit of recent testing shows I might have thrown this item away.

Since I can't kill the boss again, how can I recover it?

Answer (score 1):

This was the [response from the developer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/315460/discussions/0/1744469130475124700/):

- Try "/find metaldetector"

  - But if it has been some time ao it's gone
- Reactivate the boss spawn with "/param m_bossRespawnDelay = 10"

  - Means respawn after 10 seconds
  - Be sure to set it back to -1 after

In both cases, achievements will be disabled.